# Merging branches with large .ccfm (xml) files with with external merge tool [Git LFS]

Tags: git, gradle, git-lfs

I have a problem with merging large .ccfm (xml database) files. I have to use external 3 way merging tool that I have specified in .git/config as follows:

```
[merge]
 driver = ./gradlew runMergeTool -Pancestor=%O -Pleft=%A -Pright=%B -PconflictMarkerSize=%L -PmergeResultPath=%P
```

.gitattributes:

```
*.ccfm filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

My gradle task (written in Kotlin) then creates (git lfs smudge) the temporary files from lfs pointer files and merges the changes from right to to left. After I have resolved the conflicts manually with my external merging tool I get a following error from git:

`error: add_cacheinfo failed to refresh for path 'some_folder/another_folder/file_name.ccfm'; merge aborting.
Auto-merging some_folder/another_folder/file_name.ccfm
Done`